# How to allow optional trailing commas in macros?

Tags: macros, rust

Here's a synthetic example of what I want:

```
macro_rules! define_enum {
    ($Name:ident { $($Variant:ident),* }) => {
        pub enum $Name {
            None,
            $($Variant),*,
        }
    }
}

define_enum!(Foo { A, B });
```

This code compiles, but if add a comma to it:

```
define_enum!(Foo { A, B, });
//                     ^
```

The compilation fails. I can fix it with:

```
($Name:ident { $($Variant:ident,)* })
//                             ^
```

but then `define_enum!(Foo { A, B });` fails,

How should I write a macro to handle both cases:

```
define_enum!(Foo { A, B });
define_enum!(Foo { A, B, });
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

## Make the comma optional

[As DK. points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143327/how-to-allow-optional-trailing-commas-in-macros/43143459?noredirect=1#comment73365939_43143459), the trailing comma can be made optional.

### Rust 1.32

You can use the `?` macro repeater to write this and disallow multiple trailing commas:

```rust
($Name:ident { $($Variant:ident),* $(,)? }) => { 
//                                 ^^^^^
```

### Previous versions

This allows multiple trailing commas:

```rust
($Name:ident { $($Variant:ident),* $(,)* }) => { 
//                                 ^^^^^
```

## Handle both cases

Or you can handle both cases by... handling both cases:

```
macro_rules! define_enum {
    ($Name:ident { $($Variant:ident,)* }) => {
        pub enum $Name {
            None,
            $($Variant),*,
        }
    };
    ($Name:ident { $($Variant:ident),* }) => {
        define_enum!($Name { $($Variant,)* });
    };
}

define_enum!(Foo1 { A, B });
define_enum!(Foo2 { A, B, });

fn main() {}
```

We've moved the main implementation to the version that expects the trailing comma. We then added a second clause that matches the case with the missing comma and rewrites it to the version with a comma.

Comment: Why bother with that when you can use `$(,)*` just before the closing brace in the macro pattern?  One rule, and works for trailing comma...s.  Ok, so it's a *little* out of spec, but cuts down on repetition tremendously.

Comment: @DK. the main reason is because I didn't realize you could do that ;-) Sounds like a perfectly cromulent answer to me; please add it!

Comment: Eh, you were here first, and you've already got four Meaningless Internet Points.  Quicker to edit it into yours as an alternative for best of both.

Comment: @DK. I've edited it in, but I'd still advocate for you to add an answer yourself (and I'd edit it back out of this one). Beyond either of us gaining Magic Internet Points, the voting also allows people who come to this question to pick which answer is *better* for their uses, which is helpful for subsequent people to know what is the more idiomatic solution.

Comment: You should be aware that the second and third solutions can match one or more commas.
`define_enum!(Foo1 { , });`

Comment: The second solution also allows double-commas and just a comma with nothing else and so only the first solution should be preferred.

Answer (score 26):

Change the line

```
($Name:ident { $($Variant:ident),* }) => {
```

to

```
($Name:ident { $($Variant:ident),* $(,)? }) => {
```

to add an optional comma at the end. This works in stable Rust / 2018 edition. This syntax also works for other separators like a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (if you're using an [Incremental TT Muncher](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/tt-muncher.html)) is to use an optional capture of the delimiter + the remaining tokens. Using a slightly different example:

```rust
macro_rules! example {

    ($name:ident = $value:expr $(, $($tts:tt)*)?) => {
        println!("{} = {}", stringify!($name), $value);
        example!($($($tts)*)?);
    };

    ($value:expr $(, $($tts:tt)*)?) => {
        println!("{}", $value);
        example!($($($tts)*)?);
    };

    () => {};

}
```

This macro can then be invoked as, for example:

```rust
example! { A = 1, "B", C = 3, "D" }
```

and the trailing comma can be either included or omitted.