# Understanding the dbg! macro in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write some of my own debugging macros, and was looking at source code for rusts build in `dbg!`:

```rust
macro_rules! dbg {
    () => {
        $crate::eprintln!("[{}:{}]", $crate::file!(), $crate::line!());
    };
    ($val:expr $(,)?) => {
        // Use of `match` here is intentional because it affects the lifetimes
        // of temporaries - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48732525/1063961
        match $val {
            tmp => {
                $crate::eprintln!("[{}:{}] {} = {:#?}",
                    $crate::file!(), $crate::line!(), $crate::stringify!($val), &tmp);
                tmp
            }
        }
    };
    ($($val:expr),+ $(,)?) => {
        ($($crate::dbg!($val)),+,)
    };
}
```

Several things confuse me about this code:

1. What is `$` operator peppered throughout this code doing?
2. What the plane language equivalent of `($val:expr $(,)?)`? I don't understand what the `,` is and why it is there.
3. Why does the macro definition start with `() => {$crate::eprintln!("[{}:{}]", $crate::file!(), $crate::line!());};`?

Comment: 3. Using it as dbg!() without any parameters will output current position in the source file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is $ operator peppered throughout this code doing?

`macro_rules!` has distinct syntax on top of normal Rust. The `$`s are used to indicate metavariables (like `$ident`) and repetitions (like `$(...)`). You should probably do some preliminary research on what a Rust macro is:

- [Macros by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html) in the Rust Reference.
- [macro_rules!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/macros.html) in the Rust By Example book.
- [The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/index.html)

---

> What the plane language equivalent of `($val:expr $(,)?)`? I don't understand what the `,` is and why it is there.

The `$val:expr` defines a pattern that will match a single expression. The `$(,)?` matches a `,` that may exist zero or one times. Effectively makes it so that the `dbg!` will allow optional trailing commas (so as to mimic most of Rust). You'll see this reflected in the other pattern `$($val:expr),+ $(,)?`.

- [How to allow optional trailing commas in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143327/how-to-allow-optional-trailing-commas-in-macros)

---

> Why does the macro definition start with `() => {$crate::eprintln!("[{}:{}]", $crate::file!(), $crate::line!());};`?

This macro is designed to be called with any number of arguments, including zero. The `() => { ... };` pattern allows for `dbg!()` to be valid. The effect of calling `dbg!` with no arguments is to just log the file and line number.