# Macros with three optional parameters and one of them have to accept list of values

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have a structure with two optional fields and would like to provide special macro to simplify instances creation.

The macro have to accept one required argument and three optional arguments. Last optional argument have to accept list of values. And I would like to use exactly one patter for that.

Finally I did that and everything works fine:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Variant {
    OptionOne,
    OptionTwo,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct TheStruct{
    string: String,
    first: Option<Variant>,
    second: Option<Variant>,
    numbers: Vec<u32>,
}

impl TheStruct {
    // doesn't matter
}

#[doc(hidden)]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! the_macro_int {
    ($the_struct:ident, numbers, { $($w:expr),*$(,)*}) => {
        $($the_struct.numbers.push($w);)*
    };
    ($the_struct:ident, first, {$w:expr}) => {
        $the_struct.first = Some($w);
    };
    ($the_struct:ident, second, {$w:expr}) => {
        $the_struct.second = Some($w);
    };
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! the_macro {
    (string: $string:expr, $($kind:ident : $val:tt),*$(,)*) => {{
        let mut the_struct = $crate::TheStruct{
            string: $string,
            first: None,
            second: None,
            numbers: std::vec::Vec::new(),
        };
        $($crate::the_macro_int!(the_struct, $kind, $val);)*
        the_struct
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let the_struct = the_macro!(
        string: "Hello".to_owned(),
        first: { Variant::OptionOne },
        numbers: (1, 3, 4),
    );
    println!("the_struct:{:?}", the_struct);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b57c0ffb1868e33a0fc738ef88ccd4ae)

The one thing makes me unhappy: the brackets in `first: { Variant::OptionOne },`.

I tried to replace my pattern by `(string: $string:expr, $($kind:ident : $val:expr),*$(,)*)` but it doesn't work for `numebrs` anymore.

Is it possible to redefine pattern for `the_macro` to allow `first: Variant::OptionOne,` to be a valid while `numbers` still can accept a list of items? Kind of brackets for `numbers` doesn't matter but I can't replace list of things with just Vec or something similar.

P.S. I don't looking for a solution with multiple patterns.

Comment: I have checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373169/how-do-i-create-a-rust-macro-with-optional-parameters-using-repetitions but it didn't help me with my own question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your macro:

- First it tries to do too much. Why initialize `numbers` with `numbers: (1, 3, 4)` while array literals use `[`/`]` and you can initialize a vector with only 4 extra characters?

  Let's use the more natural notation `numbers: vec![1, 3, 4]`. This has the advantage of letting your user initialize the field with an existing vector too.
- Second, you need to use brackets around `{ Variant::OptionOne }` because you have used `tt` for your value, but `Variant::OptionOne` isn't one `tt`, it's 3. If you change the pattern to a more natural `expr`, you can use `Variant::OptionOne` directly:

  ```rust
  (string: $string:expr, $($kind:ident : $val:expr),*$(,)*) => {{
  ```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=578f05f2ec85d0966f18c4c01e8e39f6))

---

I would however advise you *not to* use such a macro. The usual way to deal with initialization of such structs in Rust is the [builder pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/ownership/builders.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the exact struct is a little bit more complicated so I can't use `just vec!` approach. Builder patter is very helpful thing but it's not what Im looking for.