# Side by side macro repetition with same separator

Tags: rust, macros

Is it actually not possible to create a macro like this or am I doing it wrong:

```
sample!("hello", "there") => 

println!("{:?}", "hello");
println!("{:?}", "there");

sample!("hello", "there", a "second type", a "another second type") => 

println!("{:?}", "hello");
println!("{:?}", "there");
println!("second {:?}", "second type");
println!("second {:?}", "another second type");
```

What I've tried is this ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3776535e8b505ced155a436b319275b3)):

```
macro_rules! sample {
  ( 
    $( $first:literal ),*
    $( a $second:literal ),*
  ) => {
      $(
        println!("{:?}", $first);
      )*
      $(
        println!("second {:?}", $second);
      )*
  };
}
```

Which fails with:

```
error: no rules expected the token `a`
  --> main.rs:18:20
   |
1  | macro_rules! sample {
   | ------------------- when calling this macro
...
18 |   sample!("hello", a "testing");
   |                    ^ no rules expected this token in macro call

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust macros are really strict with their separators.

```
macro_rules! sample {
  ( 
    $( $first:literal, )*
    $( a $second:literal ),*
  ) => {
      $(println!("{:?}", $first);)*
      $(println!("second {:?}", $second);)*
  };
}

fn main() {
  sample!("hello", a "testing");
}
```

This sample works, can you spot the change? I moved the comma from outside the first `$( ... )` to inside. The difference is:

- `$( $a:literal ),*` accepts only `"a", "b", "c"` *(no trailing comma allowed)*
- `$( $a:literal, )*` accepts only `"a", "b", "c",` *(trailing comma required)*

In your macro, the in-between comma doesn't match as part of either the first or second repetition. The error is basically saying it expected another `$first` instead of a `$second` since that's what the repetition says.

You can potentially fix it by introducing an optional comma:

```
macro_rules! sample {
  ( 
    $( $first:literal ),*
    $(,)? // <----------------
    $( a $second:literal ),*
  ) => {
      $(println!("{:?}", $first);)*
      $(println!("second {:?}", $second);)*
  };
}
```

which is more lenient but would allow weird things like this, which may or may not be okay depending on what you want.

```
sample!("hello", "there",);
sample!(, a "testing");
sample!("hello" a "testing");
```

Unfortunately, I don't know a perfect solution without using different arms like so:

```
macro_rules! sample {
  ($( $first:literal ),*) => { };
  ($( $first:literal, )* $( a $second:literal ),+) => { };
  ($( a $second:literal ),*) => { };
}

fn main() {
  sample!("hello", "there");
  sample!("hello", "there", a "testing");
  sample!(a "second type", a "another second type");
  // sample!("hello", "there",);
  // sample!(, a "testing");
  // sample!("hello" a "testing");
}
```

See also:

- [How do I create a Rust macro with optional parameters using repetitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373169/how-do-i-create-a-rust-macro-with-optional-parameters-using-repetitions?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to allow optional trailing commas in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143327/how-to-allow-optional-trailing-commas-in-macros)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it almost right- the trailing comma is tripping up the compiler. [Removing the comma works just fine.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=macro_rules!%20sample%20%7B%0A%20%20(%20%0A%20%20%20%20%24(%20%24first%3Aliteral%20)%2C*%0A%20%20%20%20%24(%20a%20%24second%3Aliteral%20)%2C*%0A%20%20)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20%24first)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20)*%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22second%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20%24second)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20)*%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20sample!(%22hello%22%20a%20%22testing%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A) If you are wondering why, it is because `macro_rules` invocations are quite picky. When it reads the trailing comma, it looks at the next token, which is `a`, but since that's not a literal, instead of doing the more sensible thing, which is checking the next pattern, it just gives up.